# Vim tab mapping not working

Tags: plugins, vim

In my **vimrc** I have tab mapped to % in visual mode, normal mode, and I think command mode with

```
:map <tab> %
"colon necessary
```

so that when I hit tab it acts as %. Everything works fine except that when in visual mode if I hit tab instead of jumping to the matching pair it just deletes whatever was visually selected. In normal and command mode this doesn't happen.

Even if I use

```
vmap <tab> %
```

in my vimrc it still doesn't work. But when I set it manually while editing a file with

```
:vmap <tab> %
```

then tab acts as % like it should.

I have supertab and snipmate btw. But even if the problem is with the plugins I don't understand why manually setting tab works when setting it in my vimrc doesn't.

Comment: Probably some plugin overwrites your vmap. Try `:verbose vmap <tab>` after starting Vim to see what it's mapped to (and by whom).

Comment: The colon is not necessary in your `~/.vimrc`. Also you should use `nnoremap` and `vnoremap` to shield your mappings from some possible conflicts.

Comment: verbose vmap <tab> showed that tab is mapped to a snipmate snippet. How do I change this?

Comment: That's at the core of how SnipMate works. I doubt that you'll be able to change it without compromizing the whole plugin's operation. And change it to what? Better stick with the defaults: `%` is great! That said, I use SnipMate too. I've added your `vmap <Tab> %` to my `~/.vimrc` and it works as it should: the selection is expanded to the matching `endif` when I hit `<Tab>` in *visual* mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've determined that overriding the default mapping doesn't do harm to the way you use the other plugin (snipMate in your case; and I think the `%` mapping is not a core one, just to avoid some corner cases potentially breaking it), you can either comment out the original mapping (`~/.vim/after/plugin/SnipMate.vim`, in your case), or (recommended, because it leaves the original plugin intact):

Create a file `~/.vim/after/plugin/zzzmappings.vim` and put your `vmap` mapping there. The `.../after/` as well as the `zzz` prefix part ensures that this is sourced last, and therefore overrides everything defined before. (Your `.vimrc`, in contrast, is sourced *before* any plugin.)

Comment: I am very confuses right now because for some reason <tab> suddenly started working like it's supposed to again. But your answer was very helpful so thanks.